# gpiozero for remote gpio control not work

Tags: gpio, pigpio, gpiozero

i just knew how to control gpio from my laptop to desire raspberry pi using gpiozero. so, i following this [docs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html#) on how to configure the raspberry pi and my laptop to performing remote gpio control. i started the pigpiod daemon on my raspberry pi using `pigpiod -n <laptop_ip_address>`, then i try to run a simple code to blink the led in pin 17 with `PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.100.2 python3 testraspi.py`. nothing happen at my raspberry pi, and i get this warning in my laptop terminal

```
/home/farhan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:277: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

does anyone has a solution ? thank you !

**EDIT**
the `ls -l` result

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhan farhan   160124 Mei  3 15:23 pigpio.py
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107545/discussion-on-question-by-farhanrbnn-gpiozero-for-remote-gpio-control-not-work).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a pin factory, gpiozero will attempt to import each library it supports in turn, until it finds one that works. It attempts in this order:

1. RPi.GPIO
2. pigpio
3. RPIO
4. Native

For each failure, you'll see a `PinFactoryFallback` warning. So if the first 3 failed and the 4th one succeeded, you'd see 3 `PinFactoryFallback` warnings and then it would proceed to run your code using the 4th (native).

This is what you got:

```py
PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

This means that it attempted to import RPi.GPIO. The import succeeded but you got RPi.GPIO's error message `This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!` This means that you have RPI.GPIO installed on your PC, which will never work. You can uninstall it. Next, gpiozero will have attempted to use pigpio, which didn't error meaning it's in use - it's presumably running your code now.

You can safely ignore the `PinFactoryFallback` warning but you probably want to get rid of it. You can do this by setting the `GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY` environment variable:

```bsh
GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=pigpio PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.100.2 python3 testraspi.py
```

You ought to verify that this is working and selecting the pigpio pin factory by running the following script with the above environment variables:

```py
from gpiozero import Device

print(Device._default_pin_factory())
```

If that shows something like:

```py
<gpiozero.pins.pigpio.PiGPIOFactory object at 0x762c26b0>
```

Then you're good.

I'm a bit concerned about what you posted as your `ls -l` result. You shouldn't have `pigpio.py` in your local directory. Make sure you delete it and install pigpio with pip:

```bsh
pip install pigpio
```